# Associate a File To a Application

Tags: c#, file-io, associations, windows-mobile-5.0, file-association

I'm building two programs, a text editor and a zipper, but in this two programs I want to associate a file type to they, but how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the  registry: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257592
You'll probably want to use regedit to see previous file associations, to make sure you don't mess up.

[c# registry basics](http://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=264)

Comment: Remember that I'm developing for Windows Mobile.

Comment: Also, I need to change something in my application to automatic show the file content?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the windows mobile tag. I've never used windows mobile, but a bit after a bit of googling, it seems that it's still done by editing the registry, not sure it's in the same place or somewhere else though

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I don't think you should be messing around with the registry like that. Especially not since ClickOnce and other deployment wizards have implemented a built-in capability to make a file-association. You can find this in **Solution Explorer -> Project Properties -> Publish tab -> Options button -> File-associations tab**. Here you have the ability to register a file-type using a custom icon, description of the file, and a program identification.

If you want to take a step ahead, you can do this with Single-instance applications as well. I did this in a tutorial project on my website:
[DrawIt](http://pieterjan.pro/?a=Projecten_csharp_DrawIt.php)
In the project I'm setting up a TCP-listener in the first instance and in the second, third, ... instance I connect a TCP-client and send the ActivationArguments to the first one.

The most important code blocks are in the file **Program.cs** and void Start_server in **Hoofdscherm.cs**.